# Investing in all assets with positive expected return and allowing for positive correlation

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio, portfolio-optimization

How does the answer to this question [Risk minimization by investing in all assets with positive expected return](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16838/risk-minimization-by-investing-in-all-assets-with-positive-expected-return) change if assets can be positively correlated (but not perfectly) and short sales are not allowed?

What if instead short sales are allowed and assets are positively correlated?